# mutate a resulting value on each row

Tags: r

Hard to word the title, I can explain better what I'm trying to do with an example:

```
bla <- data.frame(a = c(100, 2:10))
bla
     a
1  100
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
6    6
7    7
8    8
9    9
10  10
```

I would like to start with 100, then multiple this column where each rows result is passed along to the next.

Tried:

```
> bla |> mutate(cumulative = a * lag(a))
     a cumulative
1  100         NA
2    2        200
3    3          6
4    4         12
5    5         20
6    6         30
7    7         42
8    8         56
9    9         72
10  10         90
```

This gets me what I want for row 2, that is 2 * 100. But not for row 3 onwards. For row 3 I wanted 3 * 200 not 3 * 2. I.e. I want the lag based on the resulting value from the previous row.

How can I do this?

Comment: `bla |> mutate(cumulative = cumprod(a))`

Comment: Actually, it's `bla |> mutate(cumulative = c(NA, cumprod(a)[-1]))`, pretty close. Not sure why the leading `NA` is there, but it doesn't take much from the dupe-link to get there. Hope this helps.

Comment: @r2evans I'm not super clear if the `NA` is supposed to be there or not. OP shows their attempt with `lag` which doesn't work, not the desired result...

Comment: You're probably right